# Delay transition effects until after nav closes

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I close my responsive nav menu the text changes font-size before it closes and I would like to have it slide in before the font-size changes. It is constructed as such;

```
<div class="top-bar">
        <button class="top-bar__nav-toggle hamburger" id="top-nav-toggle">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </button>
        <nav class="top-bar__nav collapsed" id="top-bar__nav">
          <ul class="top-bar__nav-list nav-ul">
            <li>
              <a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navlink" href="#Portfolio">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navlink" href="#About">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="navlink" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

Styled like this;

```
.top-bar {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 2vw;
}

.top-bar__nav-toggle {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  min-width: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.hamburger {
  height: 4vw;
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger span {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 4vw;
}

.hamburger:focus span {
  background: rgb(91, 196, 221);
  outline: none;
}

.hamburger:hover span {
  background: rgb(91, 196, 221);
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 20%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}
.hamburger span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}
.hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 80%;
  transition: top 125ms 250ms, transform 125ms;
}

.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}
.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}
.hamburger.closed span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: top 125ms, transform 125ms 250ms;
}

.nav-ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.top-bar__nav {
  background: transparent;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.25s;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-bar__nav.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list {
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}

.top-bar__nav-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.top-bar__nav-list li {
  text-align: center;
}

.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list a {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.top-bar__nav-list a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 6vw;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.top-bar__nav-list a:hover {
  color: rgb(91, 196, 221);
}

.top-bar__nav-list a:focus {
  color: rgb(91, 196, 221);
  outline: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .top-bar__nav-list {
    align-items: flex-end;
    background: white;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 4vw;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .top-bar__nav.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list {
    max-height: 0;
  }

  .top-bar__nav-list.collapsed {
    padding-right: 6vw;
  }

  .nav-ul li a {
    color: gray;
  }

  .top-bar__nav-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

and animated through this code;

```
function openCloseNav() {
      var navToggle = document.querySelector("#top-nav-toggle");

      if (!navToggle.classList.contains("closed")) {
        navToggle.classList.add("closed");
        document.querySelector("#top-bar__nav").classList.remove("collapsed");
        document.querySelector("html").addEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
      } else {
        document.querySelector("#top-bar__nav").classList.add("collapsed");
        document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
        document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
        navToggle.classList.remove("closed");
        }
      }

      document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) {
          document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", watchNavClose);
          document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
          navToggle.classList.remove("closed");
          document.querySelector("#top-bar__nav").classList.add("collapsed");
        }
      })

      navToggle.addEventListener("click", openCloseNav);
  }
})

();
```

I am new to this and am not even sure how to phrase the search to find this answer. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Make another [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) that's instantaneous, with a delay on it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: I figured it out! I added a .25s transition with a 2 second delay to my '.collapsed .top-bar__nav-list a' selector and seems to be working. Scores!

Comment: It would be good to add an answer so others can use this question as a resource.